# How to make this customized bootstrap drop down effect on mouseover and mouseout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to make this customized bootstrap dropdown effect on mouseover and mouseout ?

```
 // Add slideup & fadein animation to dropdown
   $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
      var $dropdown = $(this).find('.dropdown-menu');
      var orig_margin_top = parseInt($dropdown.css('margin-top'));
      $dropdown.css({'margin-top': (orig_margin_top + 10) + 'px', opacity: 0}).animate({'margin-top': orig_margin_top + 'px', opacity: 1}, 300, function(){
         $(this).css({'margin-top':''});
      });
   });
   // Add slidedown & fadeout animation to dropdown
   $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
      var $dropdown = $(this).find('.dropdown-menu');
      var orig_margin_top = parseInt($dropdown.css('margin-top'));
      $dropdown.css({'margin-top': orig_margin_top + 'px', opacity: 1, display: 'block'}).animate({'margin-top': (orig_margin_top + 10) + 'px', opacity: 0}, 300, function(){
         $(this).css({'margin-top':'', display:''});
      });
   });
```

Comment: why don't use `data-hover="dropdown"` next to `data-toggle="dropdown"` in the 'a' tag that initiates the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger the bound events using jQuery's [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$('.dropdown').hover(
  function(){ $this.trigger('show.bs.dropdown') },
  function(){ $this.trigger('hide.bs.dropdown') }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(150);
   }, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(105)
});
```

Which i found on [bootply.](http://www.bootply.com/sevenx/90244)